# Was bedeutet "dazu eine Gleichung aufmachen"?

Tags: meaning

> Kein Wunder also, dass die Nachricht von der möglichen Olic-Rückkehr an die Elbe die HSV-Herzen zum Hüpfen bringt. „Jaaaa... bitte bitte bitte!“ jubelt MOPO-Leser Micha B. MOPO-Leser Volker H. `macht dazu eine einfache Gleichung auf`: „Olic=Fußballgott=))“ <sup>[SOURCE](http://mobil.mopo.de/hsv/hsv-fans-flehen-didi--hol--uns-ivica-olic-zurueck,23481658,29679380.html)</sup>

Ich frage mich, was der Ausdruck "dazu eine einfache Gleichung aufmachen" ist ?  Bedeutet es "to also make a simple equation"?

Comment: Ja. (12 more to go).

Comment: Nein. Es bedeutet, dass **zu diesen Thema** eine einfache Gleichung aufgestellt wird. **dazu** = **zu diesem Thema**. Richtig war aber: *Eine (mathematische) Gleichung **aufmachen*** = *Eine (mathematische) Gleichung **aufstellen***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of German used when journalists write an article in two minutes. As Kilian Foth points out, "eine Gleichung aufstellen" would be better, not making a real difference in this context. The English translation would probably be "in that respect, reader XY sets up a simple equation".

Answer (score 2):

Here, "dazu" isn't "also", it's "on that topic". And "eine Gleichung aufmachen" is to propose or posit an equation. (The more usual verb would be "aufstellen".)

Answer (score 2):

Normalerweise sagt man "eine Gleichung aufstellen". Dies bezieht sich dann aber meistens auf eine mathemathische Gleichung.

> Eine Gleichung aufmachen

sagt oft aus, dass etwas gleichgesetzt wird. In deinem Beispiel wird Olic mit einem Fußballgott gleichgesetzt. Die Aussage lautet "Für mich is Olic ein perfekter Fussballer". Dafür wird zwar eine Gleichung benutzt, aber eher um Text aufzulockern und andere Stilmittel zu verwenden. Es handelt sich um keine klassiche mathematische Gleichung wie `a² + b² = c²`.

Ich habe auf [linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/gleichung+aufmachen.html) eine weitere Bedeutung gefunden.

> Dabei müssen sekundäre oder
>   Regionalflughäfen wie Charleroi eine andere Gleichung aufmachen als europäische Großflughäfen wie
>   London, Paris oder Frankfurt.
>
> [...]airports such as Charleroi have faced a different equation from that
>   faced by the major European hubs such as London, Paris or Frankfurt.

Im Beispiel wird hier gesagt, dass etwas unterschiedlich berechnet werden muss und nicht vergleichbar ist. Diese (eventuell komplizierte) Berechnung wird im Sprachgebrauch auf eine einzelne Gleichung reduziert.

Comment: Danke! Das ist nun besser verständlich :)

Comment: Natürlich ist "Olic=Fußballgott=))" keine mathematische Gleichung, es hat aber die Form einer Gleichung und kann daher "aufgestellt" werden. Eine Gleichung "aufmachen" ist journalistischer Slang mit sehr dehnbarem Bedeutungsspektrum, alles und nichts bis zur Unverständlichkeit, denn was heißt eigentlich "Flughäfen müssen eine Gleichung aufmachen"?

Comment: Habe das Wort "meistens" eingefügt, da natürlich auch "aufstellen" benutzt werden kann/sollte.